# Uniqueness of coefficients in plane wave representation of wave equation's solution

Tags: integration, operator-theory, fourier-transform, wave-equation

3D wave equation
$$
\Delta p(\boldsymbol{r},t) - \frac{1}{c^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} p}{\partial t^{2}}(\boldsymbol{r},t) = 0 \tag{1}
$$
By applying the spatial Fourier transform to this PDE, we obtain the following ODE
$$
c^{2} |\boldsymbol{k}|^{2} \hat{p}(\boldsymbol{k},t) - \frac{\partial^{2} \hat{p}}{\partial t^{2}}(\boldsymbol{k},t) = 0 \tag{2}
$$
Since $(2)$ is ODE of harmonic oscillator, the solution can be written as
$$
\hat{p}(\boldsymbol{k},t) = A(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{ic|\boldsymbol{k}|t} + B(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{-ic|\boldsymbol{k}|t} \tag{3}
$$
Since $A=0$ by physical interpretation, apply the inverse Fourier transform to $(3)$.
$$
p(\boldsymbol{r},t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} B(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{i(\boldsymbol{k}\cdot \boldsymbol{r} - c|\boldsymbol{k}| t)} d\boldsymbol{k} \tag{4}
$$
This is plane wave representation of 3D wave equation's solution.

Now if sound pressure $p(\boldsymbol{r},t)$ is known, can the coefficients $\{B(\boldsymbol{k})\}$ be uniquely determined?

In other words, I want to know invertibility of following integral operator $\mathcal{G}$ and its inverse operator if $\mathcal{G}$ is invertible.
$$
\mathcal{G}\hat{f} (\boldsymbol{r},t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} \hat{f}(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{i(\boldsymbol{k}\cdot \boldsymbol{r} - c|\boldsymbol{k}| t)} d\boldsymbol{k} \tag{5}
$$
In the first place, it is difficult for me to calculate multiple integrals with polar coordinate component and I'm not familiar with integral operator theory.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$ p(\boldsymbol{r},t) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} B(\boldsymbol{k}) \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r} - c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t)} \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{k} = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} B(\boldsymbol{k}) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t} \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}} \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{k} = [\mathcal{F}^{-1} b (\cdot, t)] (\boldsymbol{r}) \, , $$
where $b (\boldsymbol{k}, t) = B(\boldsymbol{k}) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t}$. Since the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ is invertible (on suitable function spaces), $B$ is uniquely determined by
$$ B (\boldsymbol{k}) = b (\boldsymbol{k}, t) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t} = [\mathcal{F} p(\cdot,t)] (\boldsymbol{k}) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t} = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t}}{(2 \pi)^3} \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} p (\boldsymbol{r},t) \, \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}} \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{r} \, .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot.
That means that the operator $\mathcal{G}$ I wrote is invertible and exist its inverse operator, right?
If so, is the integral operator with any integral kernel which have no zero invertible?
$$
\mathcal{A} f (\boldsymbol{r}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}} f (\boldsymbol{k}) \kappa(\boldsymbol{k}) d\boldsymbol{k}
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
\mathcal{A} f (\boldsymbol{r}) = \mathcal{F}^{-1} b (\boldsymbol{r})
$$
where $b(\boldsymbol{k}) = f (\boldsymbol{k}) \kappa(\boldsymbol{k})/\exp{(-i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})}$. Above argument can be applied to this.

Comment: @Tsu-Fu_Samurai $\hat{f}$ can indeed be computed from $\mathcal{G} \hat{f}$ using the same method. Your generalisation, however, does not always work. Note that the kernel $\kappa$ should also depend on $\boldsymbol{r}$ (otherwise $\mathcal{A}$ maps every function to a constant and cannot be invertible anyway). $\mathcal{A} f (\boldsymbol{r})$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $b(\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{r}) = f(\boldsymbol{k}) \kappa (\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{r}) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}}$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{k}$.

Comment: @Tsu-Fu_Samurai But since $b$ already depends on $\boldsymbol{r}$, you cannot simply apply the Fourier transform to both sides to find $f$. This only works if $\kappa$ has the form $\kappa(\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{r}) = \tilde{\kappa} (\boldsymbol{k}) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}}$ (as is the case for $\mathcal{G}$ in your question with $\tilde{\kappa} (\boldsymbol{k}) = \mathrm{e}^{- \mathrm{i} c \lvert \boldsymbol{k} \rvert t}$). Then $b(\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{r}) = f(\boldsymbol{k}) \tilde{\kappa}(\boldsymbol{k})$ only depends on $\boldsymbol{k}$.

Comment: @Tsu-Fu_Samurai In this case you can invert $\mathcal{A}$ to find $f$ provided that $\tilde{\kappa}$ has no zeros.

Comment: You're right. I understand well. Thank you very much.